# Redirecting a url with urlManager in yii1.1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x, yii-url-manager

I'm trying to redirect the following url structure in Y1.1
/info/#/[string] to /site/info?value=[string]

I tried

```
 'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
  'info/#/<value:\w+>' => 'site/info',
```

And that didn't work at all

Comment: I think it has something to do with the # causing issues?

Comment: Part after `#` in URL is not sent to server at all, so I doubt you will make it work. You need to process part of URL after `#` at JS level.